404 not found page when using pagination with htaccess
I have site and it is on hosting it uses apache server and php. I need to make pagination work because currently when I visit gallery on some page 2 or 3 it says page not found 404 with this url for example domain.com/gallery/page?page=2 . My other links and routing work fine and I need them to stay the same not to be overridden by pagination config. I have directories and files in my root like this
pages
   - gallery.php
   - about_us.php

.htaccess
 router.php
 config.php
 404.php
 phpinfo.php
 index.php

my htaccess looks like this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a file or directory that exists, do nothing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redirect all requests to router.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^gallery/([0-9]+)?$ pages/gallery.php?page=$1 [L]

routing.php
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'index';
$paginated = isset($_GET['paged']) ? (int)$_GET['paged'] : 1;

switch ($page) {
    case 'home':
        include('index.php');
        break;
    case 'about_us':
        include('pages/about_us.php');
        break;
    case 'blog':
        include('pages/blog.php');
        break;
    case 'book_appointment':
        include('pages/book_appointment.php');
        break;
    case 'events':
        include('pages/events.php');
        break;
    case 'gallery':
        include('pages/gallery.php');
        break;
    case 'price_list':
        include('pages/price_list.php');
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        include('404.php');
        break;
}


?>

gallery.php
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<!-- ***** Main Banner Area Start ***** -->

<!-- ***** Main Banner Area End ***** -->

<!-- ***** Gallery Section Start ***** -->
<section class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
    <?php 
    $totalImages = 127; // Total number of images
$imagesPerPage = 9; // Images per page (3 rows of 3 images each)
$currentPage = isset($_GET['paged']) ? (int)$_GET['paged'] : 1; // Use 'paged' instead of 'page'

$startIndex = max(1, ($currentPage - 1) * $imagesPerPage + 1);
$endIndex = min($startIndex + $imagesPerPage - 1, $totalImages);

for ($i = $startIndex; $i <= $endIndex; $i += 3): ?>
  <div class="row">
    <?php for ($j = $i; $j < $i + 3 && $j <= $endIndex; $j++): 
      $filename = "galerija ($j).jpg";
      $altText = "Image $j"; ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
        <div class="gallery-item" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; padding-top: 75%;">
          <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'images/gallery/' . str_replace(' ', '%20', $filename); ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $altText; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'images/gallery/' . str_replace(' ', '%20', $filename); ?>" alt="<?php echo $altText; ?>" class="img-fluid" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </div>
<?php endfor; ?>

<div class="pagination">
  <?php 
  $totalPages = ceil($totalImages / $imagesPerPage);
  for ($page = 1; $page <= $totalPages; $page++):
  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'gallery/page?page=' . $page; ?>" class="btn btn-primary<?php echo $page === $currentPage ? ' active' : ''; ?>">
      <?php echo $page; ?>
    </a>
  <?php endfor; ?>
</div>



  </div>
</section>
<!-- ***** Gallery Section End ***** -->

<?php include('footer.php'); ?>

<!-- Include Fancybox CSS and JS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0.31/dist/fancybox.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@4.0.31/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Fancybox
  Fancybox.bind("[data-fancybox='gallery']", {
    infinite: true,
    keyboard: true,
    toolbar: true,
    buttons: [
      "zoom",
      "download",
      "thumbs",
      "close"
    ],
  });

  // Enhance keyboard navigation
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    const fancybox = Fancybox.getInstance();

    if (event.key === 'ArrowRight') {
      // Navigate to the next image
      fancybox?.next();
    } else if (event.key === 'ArrowLeft') {
      // Navigate to the previous image
      fancybox?.prev();
    } else if (event.key === 'Escape') {
      // Close the gallery
      fancybox?.close();
    }
  });
</script>

config.php
<?php
    define('BASE_URL', 'https://smashzone.rs/');
?>


Your first RewriteRule with pattern ^(.*)$ has already rewritten the request to your router.php, so that second rule never gets to do anything any more.

so what is workaround? if I remove that then my whole site breaks.

To change the order of those rules ... You always need to do the more specific stuff first, and less specific stuff later.

Although, when your system relies on one central router script already - then that should rather be handling this, instead of adding "extra" rules for each endpoint where you might need pagination.
